# Moving website on same IP from one domain TLD to another different using 301 redirect

Tags: domains, google-search-console, apache, 301-redirect, top-level-domains

If we want to move a website from one TLD to another, e.g `example.com` to `example.org`, while preserving SEO.

We intend to do the following:

1. Point both `example.com` and `example.org` to same IP where my site is working.
2. Use canonical URL to have `example.org/*` instead of `example.com/*`
3. Use 301 redirect from old TLD to new.
4. Add site to Google Webmaster Tools and make a change request.

But the big problem is we are unable to 301 redirect from `example.com` to `example.org` as both are on same IP, doing so is causing redirect loop and error.

How can I prevent the redirect looping?

Comment: What's your website platform? are you able to access files in your server/hosting? how did you implemented your 301 redirect?

Comment: Being on the same IP should not affect your redirect. Show us what you tried so we can fix it for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should redirect all requests to `example.com` to `example.org`. This works best with Apache web server:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I haven't tested it now, but it should work. Maybe you should do a rewrite from `www.example.org` to `example.org` with status code 301, and the same for `www.example.com`, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.htaccess` file for redirecting requests that come to `example.com` to `example.org`. Ensure that this rewrite rule gets fired only when the request comes to `example.com`; that way after the first redirect you will not get stuck in an infinite loop. You can test [.htaccess redirects](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) using various online htaccess web applications.